Free module of coherent sheaf of rings is coherent.
I'm reading Demailly's book Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry.I have a question on it. It says on p88. that If $\mathscr{A}$ is a coherent sheaf of rings, all free modules $\mathscr{A}^{\oplus p}$ are coherent.
I have tried to prove that. I considerd $\{F_1 , F_2, \dots ,F_n \} \subset \mathscr{A}^{\oplus n}(U), F_i = (F_i^1, \dots ,F_i^p)$. For every $G = (G_1, \dots , G_n) \in \mathscr{R}(F_1, \dots ,F_n)$, we have $\Sigma_{k=0}^{n}G_k F_k^j$ for every $j$. That's to say $G \in \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}\mathscr{R}(F_k^1, \dots ,F_k^n)$. Since $\mathscr{A}$ is coherent, each of $\mathscr{R}(F_k^1, \dots ,F_k^n)$ is finite generated. But as I know the intersection of finite generated module is not necessarily finite generated. So I have no idea how to proceed.
